# setState in componentDidMount() not working in geolocation callback

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, react-native, state

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying to use geolocation to update the state.

In componentDidMount() I can call `this.setState({lat: 1});` and it works. However if I call `this.setState({lat: 1});` from within the geolocation.getCurrentPosition() callback the app crashes. I'm testing on a physical device.

I have stripped back everything to isolate the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { AppRegistry,ScrollView, ListView, Text, View } from 'react-native';

 class TestProject extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        lat: 0
      };
  }

   componentDidMount() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
        this.setState({lat: 1}); // this causes a crash - without this line the app does not crash.
      },
       (error) => alert(error.message)
     );

     this.setState({lat: 1}); // this works
  }

   render() {
     return (
       <View>
        <Text>
          {this.state.lat}
        </Text>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestProject', () => TestProject);
```

Comment: `let self = this;
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        self.setState({
            lat: 1
        });
    },
    (error) => alert(error.message)
);`- this works for me.

Comment: @Phil it works thank you!! I though you didn't have to do this with ES6 and I couldn't find any examples using this technique? Either way thanks!

Comment: Nice to hear! Yeah ... sometimes you have to set a var/let with `this`. For example when you use an `forEach` and want to access an scope outside this `forEach`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Phil I just had to set `self = this`:

```
let self = this; 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { self.setState({ lat: 1 }); }, (error) => alert(error.message) );
```